# Finding the binary matrix assigned in one hot encoding corresponding to a category

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

I have pandas dataframe `df`. `df['downtime]` has output like this;

```
R1
R1
R2
R3
R1
NA
```

i encoded `df['downtime]` as below;

```
enc_downtime_code = OneHotEncoder()
downtime_code_enc = enc_downtime_code.fit_transform(df['downtime code'].values.reshape(-1, 1)).toarray()
```

Now i want to find the one hot binary matrix assigned to R1,R2,R3 and NA. how can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'downtime': ['R1', 'R1', 'R2', 'R3', 'R1', 'NA']})

enc_downtime_code = OneHotEncoder()
downtime_code_enc = enc_downtime_code.fit_transform(df['downtime'].values.reshape(-1, 1)).toarray()

feature_names = enc_downtime_code.get_feature_names_out(['downtime'])
encoded_matrix = pd.DataFrame(downtime_code_enc, columns=feature_names)
subset_matrix = encoded_matrix[['downtime_R1', 'downtime_R2', 'downtime_R3', 'downtime_NA']]

print(subset_matrix)
```

which returns

```
   downtime_R1  downtime_R2  downtime_R3  downtime_NA
0          1.0          0.0          0.0          0.0
1          1.0          0.0          0.0          0.0
2          0.0          1.0          0.0          0.0
3          0.0          0.0          1.0          0.0
4          1.0          0.0          0.0          0.0
5          0.0          0.0          0.0          1.0
```